# Decoupled keyboard mapping

Tags: javascript

A recent convert to the language (out of the poor death of the flash/flex platform), mostly this has been an easy transition but I seem to find dubious amounts of code duplication floating around the web.

Converting some of my AS libraries to a JS equivalent has brought the necessity for Keyboard events and in doing so have been in search for the corresponding class:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html

pretty straight forward mapping class for human readable descriptions to key codes making it far easier to code against, doing searches online raises a bit of an eyebrow with the countless implementations in various small and large libraries.

Before going ahead and creating yet another proprietary mapping I wanted to reach out and check if there exists a single definitive and maintained version of this on the web already?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

This shows the mapping of keyboard characters to the KeyCode value.

Comment: I don't believe so, when building frameworks in AS3 or Java you could rely on all parties using the underlying keyboard mapping class and not re-creating the wheel each time, as an example if I wanted to listen for the enter key simple reference Keyboard.ENTER and not the uint it corresponds against, it would seem a shame if everyone always recreated this reference?

Comment: If you use jQuery in your application, you can rely on all the keyboard button to code mappings being consistent across browsers. http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: for extended clarity if we look at these libraries [link]https://github.com/namuol/cheet.js/blob/master/cheet.js [link]https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/src/common.js why the repetition?

Comment: But if I am starting to write frameworks I would want to decouple as much as possible from any frameworks such as JQuery and therefore again why not insist all framework builders use the same source for these overly duplicated utilities?

Comment: Looking over these files they both just seem to create easier to read mappings (i.e. allowing you to check `event.which==tab` instead of `event.which==9`.  Both libraries make the same mapping. Why this hasn't been centralized? Not sure, but the underlying keyCodes are the same